# Is there a one-liner to change the values of all objects in an array in .NET?

Tags: .net

Is there a one-liner I can use to change the values of all objects in an array?

For example, I have an [empty] array of controls:

```
Dim myArr(9) As Control
```

A control is an object reference type, so I can't use each element in the array until I instantiate it:

```
myArr(0) = New Control()
```

I know how many items I need, and I know I'll need every single object to be instantiated, so is there a way to instantiate all the items in the array using a quick one-liner? Right now I'm doing this, which is OK, but it'd be nice to have a one liner.

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To myArr.Length - 1
  myArr(i) = New Control()
Next
```

Along the same lines, if I have an array of integers, how do I change all the values in a one-liner? Say I want to multiply each value by 2, for instance.

I've gotten addicted to the `.map!` function in Ruby, and I want to do something equally as elegant in .NET.

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ - I've seen code like this:

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(_ => new Control()).ToArray();
```

I'm not sure of the equivalent VB code off-hand, but I'm sure someone else can supply that if necessary - and your code does only specify ".NET" :)

Personally I'd do it explicitly though, for clarity (and it's more efficient too).

You could always create your own method to do this, of course:

```
public static T[] PopulateArray<T>(Func<T> initializer, int size)
{
    T[] ret = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
         ret[i] = initializer();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var array = PopulateArray(() => new Control(), 10);
```

Comment: Not much difference for VB.NET: `Dim array = Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(Function(i) New Control).ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

I use an Update() extension method to give myself the ability to update collections I get via LINQ queries.

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public delegate void Func<Argument>(Argument item);
    public static bool Update<SourceType>(this IEnumerable<SourceType> source, Func<SourceType> updater)
    {
        if (null == source)
            throw new ArgumentException("Update extension method was given null source.");
        if (null == updater)
            throw new ArgumentException("Update extension method was given null updater.");

        foreach (SourceType item in source)
            updater(item);

        return true;
    }
}
```

From there I just write a function which I can apply to all the items being updated. This is a simple "map" like routine. I have used this with WinForms controls, for example.